# Symfony 5 httpClient Windows AD connection

Tags: symfony, active-directory, windows-authentication, symfony-http-client

Is it possible to connect to an API with windows Credentials?
I need to connect on an API witch uses Windows AD authentication.
I thought thats works with `auth_basic` but it's not the good way...

Thanks by advance for your answers

```
$httpClient = HttpClient::create([
  'auth_basic' => ['username', 'password']
]);
$response = $httpClient->request('GET', 'https://apiURL', [
  'headers' => ['accept' => 'text/plain'],
]);
dump($response->getStatusCode());
dump($response);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possibile using the `auth_ntlm` option. But this option is supported only by the cURL client, so you must have the cURL PHP extension installed and enabled in your system.
Here's the code:

```
$httpClient = new CurlHttpClient(['auth_ntlm' => "username:password"]);
$response = $httpClient->request('GET', 'https://apiURL', [
  'headers' => ['accept' => 'text/plain'],
]);
dump($response->getStatusCode());
dump($response);
```

Comment: Thanks it's that's work fine.
I have cURL installed (it's hosted on OpenShift)